# Native Build of Qt 5.4.1 on Raspi board fails

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

I want to build Qt application on my raspi board and so I followed steps in link [Native Build Qt 5.4.1](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi). 
I used Raspbian jessie version of OS and tried to build.

It gaves me error **/usr/bin/ld.gold: internal error in make_view, at ../../gold/fileread.cc:472
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.api:115: recipe for target '../lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5.4.1' failed
make[3]:**  [../lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5.4.1] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebkit/Source'
Makefile.QtWebKit:45: recipe for target 'sub-api-pri-make_first-ordered' failed
make[2]:  **[sub-api-pri-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebkit/Source'
Makefile:351: recipe for target 'sub-Source-QtWebKit-pro-make_first-ordered' failed
make[1](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi):**  [sub-Source-QtWebKit-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi): Leaving directory '/home/pi/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebkit'
Makefile:485: recipe for target 'module-qtwebkit-make_first' failed
make:  **[module-qtwebkit-make_first] Error 2**

Is there a way to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Nail: not yet :(, but prebuilt 5.2.1 version is available in internet.